# Browsers that use compression

Tags: browser, internet

I know that [Opera Mini](http://my.opera.com/chooseopera/blog/2010/07/14/opera-mini-5-1-final-for-android) is available on Android. Are there any other browsers available that compress content to work faster when not on Wi-fi or 3g?

Comment: Do you mean can handle receiving compressed content from the originating web server, or that do something like Opera's TurboBoost that dynamically compresses anyone's originally compressed content to speed up mobile access?

Comment: @Mufasa: I mean anything like TurboBoost

Comment: Just to warn you: these sort of browsers depend on third party servers to receive, compress and feed you the webpages you want. Sensitive data isn't encrypted, and can be accessed from the third party.

Comment: Note that a lot of content today on normal http communication is already compressed through gzip. What Opera did was more than just compression, but also rewriting of HTML content to their own binary markup language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think not. A least, not efficiently. If you want to do that, you need servers, big servers, so you need a big company to run thoses big servers. So I would be very surprised if that big company doesn't advertise for its product, as Opera did.

Comment: amen brother. Its true such efforts require bandwidth and computing power. Which means money, you ain't getting that from random developers.

Answer (score 4):

There is the turbo feature in Opera Mobile -- the same UI as Mini with a more normal renderer. The compression is less effective, though.

Comment: Ha.. Ha.. Liked this answer.

Answer (score 2):

[UC Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl) is as efficient as Opera in compression.

Comment: I tried it using 2G connection and it isn't even close to Opera speed.

Answer (score 1):

There are also **UC browser** and **Puffin web browser** that have data compression feature. But I always prefer Opera Mini.

Answer (score 0):

yes! Google Chrome and [ucmini.co.in](http://ucmini.co.in) are browser that compress the website before showing the result to get fastest access. They use Proxy server for this.
Now **VPN** Enable concept will be soon launch by browser like Opera, Google, Mozilla to get result fast and accurate in upcoming version.

Answer (score 0):

UC Mini, Opera Mini and [CM Browser](http://androidpicks.com/download-cm-browser-latest-apk/) they all compress data and speed up browsing. Besides lowering image quality can also increase the websites loading speed.